# Error al hacer la partición de un dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, function, glm

Tengo este código con estos errores:

```
set.seed(123456)
trainIndex <- createDataPartition(todo$varObjBin, p=0.8, list=FALSE) 
data_train <- todo[trainIndex,]
data_test <- todo[-trainIndex,]
modeloInicial<-glm(varObjBin~.,data=data_train,family=binomial)
```

Error in createDataPartition(todo$varObjBin, p = 0.8, list = FALSE) :
y must have at least 2 data points

Error in model.frame.default(formula = varObjBin ~ ., data = data_train,  :
variable lengths differ (found for 'Rn')

He comprobado la longitud de todas las variables y es la misma.

Comment: puedes editar el post , y separa el código de los errores???

Comment: Hola, amigo te recomiendo que pases por aquí: [tour] y que te leas estos artículos: [help/dont-ask], [help/on-topic], [help/behavior] y que arregles tu pregunta mirando este articulo: [mcve] tambien puedes pedir ayuda en: [chat]

Comment: ¿Qué te retorna `length(todo$varObjBin)`?

Comment: me sale que tiene una longitud de 0

Answer (score 0):

No se si te sirve pero puedes particionar un data.frame de la siguiente manera:

```
  set.seed(1234)
  dim_data <- dim(df)[1]
  sample_1 <- sample(x = dim_data, size = 0.8 * dim_data, replace = FALSE)
  data_train <- df[c(sample_1), ]
  data_test  <- df[-c(sample_1), ]
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! ya está solucionado